# Smart UV project is ordering my faces incorrectly

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a png texture which I am trying to paste onto a soda can:
[image]

but when I UV uwrap, it looks like this, the logo is in two different parts of the can, and its upside down:

[image]

[image]

I suspect this is because my UV unwrapping is not 'numbering' the faces correctly and 'flipping' faces randomly for no reason. The screenshot below shows I have selected consecutive faces. But the UV has ordered them in the weirdest way possible.

[image]

What can I do to fix my UV unwrapping?

Here is the blender file if you'd like to investigate:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how it determines where to cut for a cylinder but it looks like Smart UV Project will give separate UVs, which is not what you want. For this kind of object, choose the front view and unwrap with the Cylinder Projection instead and scale on Y in the UV Editor

Answer (score 1):

You should mark edges as seams on your model(Ctrl+E -> M), then unwrap UVs(U->U), then move and rotate the UVs on your texture to get desired results.

If you had a more detailed soda can with the form getting narrower at the top, unwrapping would not produce UV island that is straight. [UvSquares add-on](https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares) is very helpful in situations like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already solved the problem with the other answer, here is a hack that should work. There are probably a lot of unnecessary details.

In the UV Editor of your .blend file, turn on UV Sync (1) and Vertex Select Mode (2). Then select the top row of vertices (3):

[image]

In the 3D viewport you will have this. I used Shift->Z to make it easier to see:

[image]

I put the 3D viewport into Front Orthographic view and selected all the edges:

[image]

The pressed Delete, but deleted Faces:

[image]

Select the top edge of what remains:

[image]

Shift->D to duplicate it. Press ESC to not move it. Then separate it by pressing P and choosing Selection:

[image]

Go into Object mode and choose the separated BezierCurve.002. Then Edit Mode, select the edge and E Z 10 to extrude a new section for the can.

Select all of what was just extruded and assign the Red Metal Material to it as it originally was:

[image]

Then select an edge and Mark Seam. Select all and for this unwrap, I used the Unwrap method:

[image]

It gives this result. You can select a line of vertices to see which is the top and rotate it accordingly, after selecting everything, if you want the top at the top:

[image]

[image]

In the UV Menu I checked Constrain To Image Bounds and moved the unwrap onto the image. I turned on Display Stretch:

[image]

[image]

Then S Y to fill the image:

[image]

If you want a bit of a margin around the unwrap just scale it in a bit.

In Object Mode you can join this new part to the base Ctrl->J